# Getting counts of grouped fields, but also need field names with zero counts

Tags: php, mysql

you've probably seen it before. I'm trying to get the counts of how many sms messages belong in folders, but I want to still have the field named show up that don't contain any smses.

For Example:

```
TABLE: inbox_compiled
message_text(text)
id_folder(int)     

TABLE: user_folders
id_folder(int)
name(text)
```

This is the mysql statement I use:

```
SELECT 
user_folders.id_folder, name, COUNT(*) as msg_count 
FROM inbox_compiled, user_folders 
WHERE 
inbox_compiled.id_folder = user_folders.id_folder
GROUP BY name ORDER BY msg_count DESC


My results are this:
id_folder,name,msg_count
'1', 'inbox', '25'
'2', 'outbox', '1'
```

What I should (or would like to) get is this):

```
id_folder,name,msg_count
'1', 'inbox', '25'
'2', 'outbox', '1'
'3', 'spam', '0'
'4', 'personal', '0'
'5', 'junk', '0'
```

(I know the table fields aren't the best - it's what I'm working with right now)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
SELECT 
user_folders.id_folder, name, COUNT(inbox_compiled.id_folder) as msg_count 
FROM user_folders left join inbox_compiled on (inbox_compiled.id_folder = user_folders.id_folder)
GROUP BY name ORDER BY msg_count DESC;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks OIS! :) Now I shall got and study how it works.

Comment: @vr_driver not complicated you can look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) to see basic think of left join syntax, also i suggest you to take a look at JOIN syntax in general it's much better to use that then comma separated old way of joining table like you did in your query. Just google a little about that :) GL!

Answer (score 0):

Use outer join and also do not use count(*) but just count the message ids, e.g.

```
select f.id_folder, f.name, i.*, count(i.id) as msg_count from user_folders as f left join inbox_compiled as i on i.id_folder = f.id_folder group by f.name;
```